# how to reserve a running amazon ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

we have a large ec2 instance running in asia pacific region.we want to reserve *that* particular instance.In aws management console we see an option to purchase a reserved  instance but there seems to be no option to change this instance into a reserved one.Are we missing out on something

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Reserved instances are a billing feature, not a technical feature.

You can purchase a reserved instance and the discounted hourly rate will apply to already-running instances, without needing to do anything to them.
Just make sure the reserved instances you purchase are:
- in the same availability zone as your already-running instances
- of the same instance type (m1.small, c1.medium, etc) as your already-running instances.

As soon as the reservation cost clears your credit card you will see the discounted hourly rate take effect for your already-running instances.

Amazon's docs could be a lot clearer on this. 
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/#4

Comment: As for the availability zone: Does it have to be specific till the last letter? i.e. do my reserved instance and on-demand instance have to be in "us-east-1a" or they both being in US East North Virginia is sufficient?

Comment: @Jayesh That's actually a different question, for which the comments are note the right place. However, according to AWS terminology, 'us-east-1a' is an Availability Zone, while 'us-east-1' is a Region. So yes, the AZ in which you reserve and run instances has to match.

Answer (score 6):

The AWS's official docs state that the availability zone must be the same. The region is, for example, `us-east-1`. The AZ is `us-east-1a`. So, according to AWS, it has to be specific to the last letter.

However, some clever folks found a [potential work-around](http://shlomoswidler.com/2010/03/ec2-reserved-instance-availability-zone-problem-no-problem.html) that uses EC2 Consolidated Billing and combines the (odd?) feature that one's us-east-1a might be another `us-east-1c` (I guess the idea there is to enforce some homogeneity around the AZs).