# How to change platform of Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have an on-demand instance running in Amazon EC2. I want to create a reserved instance. 
My instance configuration is

```
Instance type :m1.small
Availability zone:us-west-2c
Platform: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4
```

I have set up this instance with all required software to run my web service (30GB EBS is attached to this instance)

Got to know how to create a reserved instance [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821324/how-to-reserve-a-running-amazon-ec2-instance). When I was about to purchase a reserved instance, I noticed that Linux/UNIX is cost effective than Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Is there any way I can change my running instance platform or Should I redo every setup with a new instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to replace the instance's platform (and pricing) and maintaining its current deployment. I've found [this](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/mount-ebs-volume-created-from-snapshot.html) article about a workaround for 'sharing EBS' but it doesn't guarantee that an EBS volume created for RHEL can be attached to a Linux instance (I'd bet against it).

If you already paid for reserved instances, I suggest you contact aws support team to see if there are any alternatives, or at least - a refund.
(BTW please update us if there is a solution)

Comment: You are right. I tried adding existing RHEL EBS to my newly created Ubuntu instance as root device. It worked but I could not access my old files. So created new Ubuntu instance with EBS and did the entire set up again:(