# Reserving instance in Amazon ec2 with different platform

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my on-demand instance running in Amazon EC2 and following is the instance details.

```
Instance type :m1.small
Availability zone:us-west-2c
Platform: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4
```

I have set up this instance with all required software to run my web service (30GB EBS is attached to this instance)

Now I want to convert it as a reserved instance.Got to know how to create a reserved instance [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821324/how-to-reserve-a-running-amazon-ec2-instance). Will it be converted as reserved instance if I purchase an instance with platform as Linux/Unix as it is cost effective instead of Red Hat Enterprise Linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHEL has additional licencing costs over the base Linux instances. You would need to purchase a reserved instance with REHL or set up your instance with something like Amazon Linux.

Comment: I see only Amazon Linux AMI in the Quick Start while creating instance. Will Ubuntu Server 13.10 be suitable for my case?

Comment: It should be. If you prefer the Redhat style environment, you should be able to find Fedora or CentOS images as well.

Comment: Can I just create an instance with Ubuntu and attach my already set up EBS? I have few things installed in it.

Comment: You can attach the volume, but not as a root volume.

Comment: You are right. I tried adding existing RHEL EBS to my newly created Ubuntu instance as root device. It worked but I could not access my old files. So created new Ubuntu instance with EBS and did the entire set up again.